# Cron: Only get errors in emails?

Tags: bash, shell, cron, schedule

I finally set up a realistic backup schedule on my data through a shell script, which are handled by cron on tight intervals. Unfortunately, I keep getting empty emails each time the CRON has been executed and not only when things go wrong.

Is it possible to only make CRON send emails when something goes wrong, ie. my `TAR` doesn't execute as intended?

Here's how my crontab is setup for the moment;

```
0 */2 * * * /bin/backup.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "Backup status" email@example.com
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Ideally you'd want your backup script to output nothing if everything goes as expected and only produce output when something goes wrong.  Then use the MAILTO environment variable to send any output generated by your script to your email address.

```
MAILTO=email@example.com
0 */2 * * * /bin/backup.sh
```

If your script normally produces output but you don't care about it in cron, just sent it to /dev/null and it'll email you only when something is written to stderr.

```
MAILTO=email@example.com
0 */2 * * * /bin/backup.sh > /dev/null
```

Comment: This is hardly ideal. You generally want the entire output (stdout + stderr) e-mailed to you when the command ends with a non-zero error code. Otherwise, it is generally fine to gobble at least stdout. To me, this is a design flaw of cron.

Comment: @Witiko I agree; I found this question trying to fix that. I guess you can make your cron command `/bin/backup.sh > log_file || (echo Backup failed with exit status $?; cat log_file)`?

Comment: @DanielH That can work as long as /bin/backup.sh can run exclusively.

Comment: Be careful. The MAILTO setting will apply for all following cronjobs in your crontab.

Answer (score 36):

Using [cronic](https://habilis.net/cronic/) wrapper script looks like a good idea; to use it you don't have to change your scripts.

Instead of:

```
 0 1 * * * /bin/backup.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "Backup status" email@example.com
```

do:

```
 MAILTO=email@example.com
 0 1 * * * cronic /bin/backup.sh
```

Simply put; it will run silent if everything runs smooth (exit status 0), but it will report verbosely if not, and let cron handle the mail reporting.

More info on https://habilis.net/cronic/.

Comment: I really don't see how that will help when the problem is nothing more than an incorrect cron line and cron is doing exactly what it is told to do.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers it helps because sometimes you have output without an error.

Comment: Alternatively, `chronic` from the `moreutils` package: https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/

Comment: Not sure why everyone is upvoting chronic (vs cronic). All I could find about their difference is: `Joey Hess has written a simpler perl version of cronic named chronic` (cronic man page, https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/cronic.1.html). However in my case cronic worked just fine.

Answer (score 13):

Here is another variation that I've successfully utilized for many years - capture output and print it out **only on error**, triggering an email.  This requires no temp files, and **preserves all output**.  The important part is the `2>&1` that redirects STDERR to STDOUT.

#### Send the entire output via default cron mailer config:

```
1 2 * * * OUTPUT=`flexbackup -set all 2>&1` || echo "$OUTPUT"
```

#### Same but with a specific address and subject:

(address can also be changed by setting [MAILTO=xxxx](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) for the entire crontab file)

```
1 2 * * * OUTPUT=`flexbackup -set all 2>&1` || echo "$OUTPUT" | mail -s "Failed to backup" an@email.address
```

#### You can even perform multiple actions on error and add to email:

```
1 2 * * * OUTPUT=`flexbackup -set all 2>&1` || {echo "$OUTPUT" ; ls -ltr /backup/dir ; }
```

This will work for simple commands.  If you are dealing with complex pipes (`find / -type f | grep -v bla | tar something-or-other`), then you're better off moving the command into a script and running the script using the aforementioned approach.  The reason is that if any part of the pipe outputs to STDERR, you'll still get emails.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very common problem, and nowadays (2021), best solved using "chronic" from the **moreutils** package, which is done exactly for this purpose. This package is available in most linux/bsd distribution.

- https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/
- https://git.joeyh.name/index.cgi/moreutils.git/

```
chronic runs a command, and arranges for its standard out and standard error to only be displayed if the command fails (exits nonzero or crashes). If the command succeeds, any extraneous output will be hidden.

A common use for chronic is for running a cron job. Rather than trying to keep the command quiet, and having to deal with mails containing accidental output when it succeeds, and not verbose enough output when it fails, you can just run it verbosely always, and use chronic to hide the successful output.

        0 1 * * * chronic backup # instead of backup >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I hope it's ok that I've pasted the text here for quicker details.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Thanks for providing an example.

Answer (score 4):

You are specifically instructing `cron` to always send email, even when `/bin/backup.sh` (by the way,  it should be in `/usr/local/bin`) succeeds.  Just omit the `| mail -s "Backup status" email@example.com` part and email will only be sent when there is output.  You can probably (depending on your `cron`) explicitly set the email address to mail to as an assignment in the crontab file.

For details, see

```
man 5 crontab
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be directing the `stderr` anmd not both `stdout` and `stderr`.

Use `1> /dev/null` not `2>&1` and it should be fine. Also, you may need to report the error correctly in your backup script.